# Uncaught LogicException: The cache must return instances of ClassMetadata, but got 1

Tags: symfony-3.4, debian-stretch, php-7.3

Trying to boot up Symfony app 3.4 with php 7.3 throws an exception:

Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: The cache must return instances of ClassMetadata, but got 1. in /var/www/contoso/vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/MetadataFactory.php:73 Stack trace:

.0 /var/www/contoso/vendor/jms/security-extra-bundle/Security/Authorization/Interception/SecurityPointcut.php(84): Metadata\MetadataFactory->getMetadataForClass('AppBundle\Contr...')

.1 /var/www/contoso/vendor/jms/aop-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PointcutMatchingPass.php(149): JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Security\Authorization\Interception\SecurityPointcut->matchesMethod(Object(ReflectionMethod))

.2 /var/www/contoso/vendor/jms/aop-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PointcutMatchingPass.php(65): JMS\AopBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PointcutMatchingPass->processDefinition(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition), Array, Array)

.3 /var/www/contoso/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Sy in /var/www/contoso/vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/MetadataFactory.php on line 73

I Changed the file permissions with chmod 777 to the app/cache and app/logs folder but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, After many hours I figure out that this problem is for the memcached extension.
So I end up installing with phpbrew.

```
phpbrew ext install memcached stable
phpbrew ext enable memached
```

I found a reference based on [this thread](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/673) on GitHub

If you are not using phpbrew try [this link](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-memcache-extension)